# Modifying Objects within ArrayList

Tags: java, database, arrays, oop, arraylist

I was in need of a dynamic "database" of objects and after some research, decided to use ArrayList. However, I cannot modify the arraylist with the code as follows:

```
public static ArrayList cprofiles;
...
cprofiles = new ArrayList();
...
...
Customer newc = new Customer (lna, fna, sinum, year, month, day);
cprofiles.add (newc);
```

After this declaration, I am trying to call to methods within the object using the following format `cprofiles.get(0).getName()` but I am getting an error stating

> cannot find symbol (pointing to .getName())

when I try to compile the program. I have spent about an hour researching the proper method to modify this in an ArrayList but the sources I have found seem to suggest that I what I am doing is indeed correct.
Please aid me spotting my error and how I may fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: It might also be that `cprofiles.get(0)` need to be casted (or the list to be `new ArrayList<Customer>()`).

Comment: or public static ArrayList<Customer> cprofiles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the generic version of ArrayList, and not the raw version:

```
List<Customer> cprofiles = new ArrayList<Customer>();
```

If you just use `ArrayList`, the compiler doesn't know what your list contains, so everything is considered as an `Object`. And you thus need to cast the returned object to its actual type:

```
Customer c = (Customer) list.get(0);
```

Comment: Ah damn. How did I miss that. Thought he had declared an ArrayList with the type parameter. Haste makes waste :)

Comment: @bot you mean "*haste* makes waste"?

Comment: Proved that point once again. :). Auto correct on mobile phone keyboards can sometimes be a pain.

Comment: Semi-related question: Can Collections.sort() now be applied to the name in each object? If so, what would be the syntax for this?